# When bringing Android activities from the stack to the front, how do I refresh (reinitialize) them? So to run onCreate again etc

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

If I'm bringing Android activities from the stack to the front, how do I refresh them? So to run onCreate again etc.

My code below, in conjunction with setting activities in the Android manifest to *android:launchMode="singleTask"* allows me to initiate an activity if that activity is not already active within the stack, if it is active within the stack it is then brought to the front.

How do I then, if the activity is brought to the front refresh it so that onCreate is ran again etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this,
        myActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Put the code in `onResume` method. You cannot call onCreate unless you completely destroy the activity and it restarts again...

Comment: Based on your question, the comments and the answers here I think you are barking up the wrong tree. You are trying to abuse all the standard workflow and navigation mechanisms that Android provides you and you are generating more problems for yourself. I suggest you explain what the desired behaviour is and maybe someobody can help you correct your architecture. Unless you have a really good reason, you shouldn't be using `launchMode="singleTask" and the only reason to rearrange activities is if you want to preserve their state. Bringing an activity to the front and then reinitializing it ...

Answer (score 1):

I think FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will resolved your problem:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myActivity.this, myActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is refresh the content, you should override the `onResume` method, and add in the code to perform the refresh in this method. To do this, use the following code **within the activity that you want to perform the refresh**, (ie, not the same activity that you are calling `startActivity()` from):

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //add your code to refresh the content
}
```

**Tip:** If you are using Android Studio, press Alt+Insert (while you have the Java file open), then click `Override Methods`, find `onResume`, and it should provide you with a basic template for the method.

[image: Activity Lifecycle]

The diagram I added shows the order that the methods are run (this is known as the *Activity Lifecycle*). `onCreate()` is run whenever an Activity is first created, followed by `onStart()`, followed by `onResume()`. As you can see, when a user returns to an Activity, `onCreate()` is not run again. Instead, `onResume()` is the first method that is called. Therefore, by putting your code into the `onResume()` method, it will be run when the user returns to the activity. (Unlike `onCreate()`, which will not be run again).

**Extra info:** Since you will be initially setting the data in `onCreate()` and then refreshing it within `onResume()`, you might want to consider moving all of your code used to initially set the data to `onResume()` as well. This will prevent redundancy.

**Edit**: Based on your following comment, I can give the following solution:

> I'm wanting to properly refresh the page, e.g. if there is a variable count initialised at 0. And though running the activity it's has became equal to 300. When the activity is called (intent) then refreshed, count will once again be equal to it's initial value. Do you know how to do this?

Without your current activity's code, there is not much to work with, but here is some pseudo-code as to how I would accomplish your problem:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView numberTextView;
    int numberToDisplay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(myContent);

        numberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
        numberTextView.setText(numberToDisplay+"")//converts the integer to a string
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        numberToDisplay = 0;
        numberTextView.setText(numberToDisplay+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do that programmatically? You can see from my code above how I'm opening or rearranging activities.

Comment: I've added a template for the `onResume()` method to the answer.

Comment: And that will refresh the page content, when I use my code to reorganise and bring to front activities from within the stack? Or do I need to add something in place of your comment?

Comment: Although what you have wrote is extremely informative, it doesn't actually answer my question. What code, would you suggest to place there?

Comment: Post your existing code so I can try and show you, with what you currently have there is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: It depends on the context of your application what you would place there. What are you refreshing? Is it a ListView, or some other type of data that is accessing the web? What is your current `onCreate()` method?

Comment: I'm wanting to properly refresh the page, e.g. if there is a variable count initialised at 0. And though running the activity it's has became equal to 300. When the activity is called (intent) then refreshed, count will once again be equal to it's initial value. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I have added an example to the bottom of an answer giving an example of how to use `onResume()` to refresh a counter. This will make the counter reset to zero every time that the activity is brought to the user's screen.

Comment: Is there not a method to simply globally reset all variables to their original values?

Comment: No, that's not possible. These types of things need to be done manually.

Comment: How can I reset arrays of textviews or reinitialise ?

Comment: That cannot be answered, it is dependent on your currently existing code. I suggest editing your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an explicit way to refresh onCreate, perhaps you may want to add the code you want reloaded into `onResume`.

This workaround may work if you want to keep your code in `onCreate`.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: You can see from my code above, how I'm opening or rearranging activities. Where should I add this, and will this definitely refresh the page which is being reorganised and brought to the front?

Comment: It's ugly, but after you call startActivity the first time (in your code), you can try calling finish(), and startActivity once again (adding my two lines to the end of your code). That being said, refreshing based on onResume may be something to look into.